# Do these values of bias and variance make sense?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, variance, bias

I have this code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
model = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

from mlxtend.evaluate import bias_variance_decomp

print(y_train.min(), y_train.max(), y_test.min(), y_test.max())
#for your understanding of the data: 7283 517924 11510 450000

avg_expected_loss, avg_bias, avg_var = bias_variance_decomp(
        model, X_train, y_train.ravel(), X_test, y_test.ravel(), 
        loss='mse', random_seed=1)

print('Average expected loss: %.3f' % avg_expected_loss)
print('Average bias: %.3f' % avg_bias)
print('Average variance: %.3f' % avg_var)
```

The result is:

```
Average expected loss: 542162695.679
Average bias: 529311955.129
Average variance: 12850740.550
```

To me, these values seem to be too high. Am I missing something or this correct?

Comment: Hello Kasofi. To me these values make sense as we can see the values of x and y are huge ( > 1000). Why don't you try to normalize these values or divide them by a factor (for example 1000) and see what it changes for the loss, bias and variance ? you can try using [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) to normalize.

Comment: Using normalization I get smaller values, obviously :D but also, my model performes worse. And thanks :)

Comment: I'm surprised normalizing the data change a linear regression performance :o. But anyway if you are wondering about why your loss, bias and variance values are so big, it is obviously linked to the fact that your input values are big. You should try plotting your inputs / outputs to see what kind of preprocessing could make sense. I just checked sklearn site, and maybe standardScaler is more effective than normalizing. Another interesting measure that doesn't depend on scale of values can be r^2 (correlation).